# Are the following propositions tautologies?...

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Are the following propositions tautologies?...

1.) $[\neg p \wedge (p \vee q)] \rightarrow q$

2.) $[p \wedge (p \rightarrow q)] \rightarrow q$

I'm not sure if I have done a right truth table for the first one:

p | q | $\neg p$ | $(p \vee q)$ | $\neg p \wedge (p \vee q) \rightarrow q$ |

T | T |    F..     | ....T.......|...........T...............|

T | F |   F..   |  ....T.......|...........T...............|

F | T | T..    |   ....T...... |...........T...............|

F | F | T..    |    ....F.......|...........T...............|

My question on this is that, do I have to add a column for "$\rightarrow q$" before the final expression or what I have is fine? Having all T's means it's a tautology. 
Also I just kind of got into the logic laws, and if I wanted to use the laws, how would I start on the first problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend adding a column for $\neg p \wedge (p \vee q)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both are tautologies.

Notice that $\neg p \lor q \equiv p \to q$. So 1) is a special case of 2). Now, 2) ought to remind you of *modus ponens*.

I recommend that you have  a column for each subformula — don't skip any, especially when first learning. Thus: for 1), you should add a column, 2nd from right, for $\neg p\land(p\lor q)$. Similarly, for 2), the 2nd-to-last column should be $p\land(p\to q)$.

There's no guesswork involved: it's mechanical to compute the remaining truth values, column by column, once every subformula is a column heading. Furthermore, it makes it much easier (likewise mechanical) to check your work.

Comment: So for the first problem, I can make a column for "$\rightarrow q$"?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. I added a little to my answer and hopefully made it clearer/better.

Comment: The proposed heading you keep asking about, $\to q$, isn't a well-formed formula, you can't make a column for *that*. Make a column for each *subformula*, not for every *substring*.

Comment: Ah, I see. It makes more sense now. It's just I saw someone else separate everything and made a column for each one, which confused me. Thank You.

Comment: Ohh. If I understand correctly, that's interesting. Yes in an alternate approach you could use the formula itself as the column heading row, loosely speaking (no data columns for parens), and you'd fill in the columns, in a complicated order, from the variables up through the connectives till you reach the topmost connective, $\to$ here. But if you just list the subformulas by "depth" starting at the bottom (variables), then you fill in the columns from left to right — simple.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For the first formula you can start like this

$\begin{align}
\left[\neg p \land (p \lor q)\right] \implies q \\
\left[(\neg p \land p) \lor (\neg p \land q)\right] \implies q\\
\dots
\end{align}$

I just used the distributivity of $\land$ (with respect to $\lor$), that is $a \land (b \lor c) \equiv (a \land b) \lor (a \land c)$. Let's simplify what we've got so far:

$\begin{align}
\left[(\neg p \land p) \lor (\neg p \land q)\right] \implies q\\
\left[False \lor (\neg p \land q)\right] \implies q\\
\left[(\neg p \land q)\right] \implies q\\
\end{align}$

Notice that $\neg p \land p$ can never be $True$, but since a disjunction ($\lor$) is already $True$ if one term is $True$, we can safely ignore this term.  Now use the fact that $a \implies$ b is logically equivalent to $\neg(a \land \neg b)$. In this case $a := (\neg p \land q)$ and $b := q$. Can you do it now?

Comment: I have used distributivity of $\wedge$ but was stuck afterwards. Can you help me with the first one, and then I'll try the second one on my own.

Comment: Yes, you provided me a good illustration. Thank you for the help.